# how to make animatorInflater correct?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to correct `AnimatorInflater` but it doesn't work and I can't find my error.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.administrator.propertyanimation;

import android.animation.AnimatorInflater;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.util.*;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button mbttn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mbttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);


        ObjectAnimator anim = (ObjectAnimator) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(MainActivity.this, R.animator.propertyanimation);
                anim.setTarget(mbttn);
        anim.start();

        return ;
    }
}
```

propertyanimation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="360"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

This is the logcat output:

```
03-27 10:27:05.422    3825-3825/com.example.administrator.propertyanimation E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.administrator.propertyanimation, PID: 3825
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.administrator.propertyanimation/com.example.administrator.propertyanimation.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.animation.AnimatorSet cannot be cast to android.animation.ObjectAnimator
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.animation.AnimatorSet cannot be cast to android.animation.ObjectAnimator
            at com.example.administrator.propertyanimation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-27 10:27:05.434      584-596/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity
```

Then a dialog always appears that says "Unfortunely, Activity has stopped"

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: You probably want to show your propertyanimation.xml too.

Comment: @ci_ i have added some information,could you help me check where my error is? thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're loading an `AnimatorSet` and then try to assign it to an `ObjectAnimator`, which gives you the exception you see in logcat.

Remove the `set` tag from your propertyanimation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="360"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the set because you want to add to it later, you can change your code to load an `AnimatorSet` instead like this:

```
AnimatorSet anim = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(MainActivity.this, R.animator.propertyanimation);
```